# A closed 0-form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Sorry, this question may seems a bit pedantic and trivial.

In the language of differential forms, if $f$ is a zero-form, and I get $df = 0$ with $d$ being the exterior derivative. Then we know $f = C$ where C is some constant number. I was wondering if there is a particular proposition or theorem to justify this. I am not talking about basic calculus because that is trivially true. However, in the language of differential forms, do we need a few more steps to jump from $df=0$ to $f = C$?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually $f$ constant on each connected component. Prove the claim for functions on connected manifolds first.  Suppose $f : M \to \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth map on a connected manifold with $df=0$. Fix a point $p \in M$, you want to show that the set 
$$
\mathcal{C} =\{ q\in M \mid f(q)=f(p) \}
$$
is open and closed in $M$. Hence $\mathcal{C} = M$ which means that $f$ is constant on $M$. The set $\mathcal{C}$ is closed trivially. Show $\mathcal{C}$ is open by using charts and result in elementary calculus.

Comment: Hello Sou, I was wondering, if $f$ is defined on the unit sphere, which is the boundary of a unit ball, does $f$ even have partial derivatives well-defined? I asks this because, in general for a smooth function 0-form, $df$ is the sum of partial derivatives times $dx_i$.

Comment: Um, never mind, a 0-form is a smooth function by definition, so the partial derivatives are well-defined for sure.